# cycles material displacement based on gradient texture

Tags: cycles-render-engine, displacement

I have a simple cycles material displacement setup where the mesh is being displaced by a texture, using nodes (NOT the displacement modifier). Everything's working great except I the mesh I'm making is a landscape mesh with a mountain and a desert surrounding it; I only want the displacement on the mountain, but (possibly a different or) no displacement on the rest of the mesh.

For change of materials, I have a simple gradient texture (set to spherical) setup to change the value of "Mix Shaders" to get only the mountain material around the mountain area, and the rest a different material, but I also need the displacement for the mountain and the rest of the mesh to be different.

Is there any way to map the displacement to the same gradient texture that I have now, or constrain the displacement in some other way?

Comment: Use the same spherical gradient as mask for a color mix node driving the displacement

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Thanks that worked perfectly!

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Is there a way to have a different displacement for the rest of the mesh?